# 3d-force-graph flashing graph node

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, 3d

I'm using the library ([3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph)),I started to implement the graphic with images as nodes, when I do some interaction to change the color of the node, the node starts blinking

[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqPhc.png)

Here's a basic demo I did on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qxfmyz?file=src%2Fmain.ts

In the demo, I made an interaction when I click on the node it changes color, indicating that this node is selected, sometimes this interaction is making the nodes of the graph blink

I searched in some forums and in the library's git issues, but I couldn't find something effective to solve the problem, I would like some help to solve the problem

I tested some library functions and searched some forums to find something to solve the problem